# IS location comming from network provider or gps

Tags: android

```
if (viaGps) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (viaNetwork) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
Log.d("", "lat: "+location.getLatitude()+" lon: "+location.getLongitude());
```

i want to know if both of my conditions are true then from where the below latitude and longitude are comming ? is these are comming from `gps` or `network_prvider`. `locationManager` is listenig to location updates via both.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Location object you have a method called getProvider()

you can do something like below

```
if (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(location.getProvider())) {

        } else if (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.equals(location.getProvider())) {

        }
```